# NSXMLParser determine if a tag is an empty-element-tag

Tags: objective-c, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I am using NSXMLParser to parse an XML file that has empty-element-tags:

```
<SAMPLETAG />
```

and start and end tags:

```
<SAMPLETAG>
</SAMPLETAG>
```

I am using the NSXMLParserDelegate methods:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

Now my problem is that the delegate methods I am using do not tell me if the tag is empty or a start-tag. I would really like to know what kind of tag it is! Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: I'm searching answer to very same thing. If you find a solution please - share!

Comment: Well actually I have found kind of an answer. The thing is that both styles of writing the tag are the same. At least they should be interpreted as being the same by any xml parser.
So for the <SAMPLETAG /> first the delegate didStartElement method is called and is followed by a call to the didEndElement method. You should interpret <SAMPLETAG /> as <SAMPLETAG></SAMPLETAG> because they are the same thing by definition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to check the tag empty or a start-tag, but you might consider to do some regex correction before parsing, such as replace all <"SAMPLETAG/"> with <"SAMPLETAG">
<"/SAMPLETAG"> (ignore quotes, if I type without quotes, it can't display right). this is my way to process this problem.